# Questions are duplicates of each other?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I just found two highly upvoted questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-delete-without-putting-text-in-the-register) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638542/any-way-to-delete-in-vim-without-overwriting-your-last-yank).

The funny thing is that they're both marked as duplicates of the other one. Of course, the first link is only flagged and hasn't been closed (unlike the second), but it got me thinking; obviously if two or more questions really are duplicates of each other, we don't want them to all end up closed, as that would be counterproductive.

So are there currently any systems in place to ensure that duplicate "loops" don't occur? If not, should we make it impossible to close as a duplicate of a question that was closed as a duplicate of something that traces back to the original question?

Comment: @iStimple I'm aware of that. It simply got me thinking about what could happen if it was.

Comment: There's actually a question marked as a duplicate of itself. I don't remember what it was though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried it and there is indeed a system in place:

[image]

So, this probably won't happen any time in the future.